# White covering on leaves of tulsi (holy basil) in winters

Tags: diseases, fungus, basil, outdoor

[image: tulsi problem]

[Full gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX62S.jpg)

Facing the same problem in 3 of my 4 tulsi plants

Looks like a fungal infection to me, please advice. Happening in winters. It appears to have spread to 2 plants from one. Other non-tulsi plants seem unaffected.